# php Creating Multiple Image files with unique serial numbers getting error

Tags: php, image, header

I have a function set up to create multiple images with unique serial numbers on each of them. The problem is that its creating a small square on the browser and not redirecting the browser after saving back to the dashboard

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
$imgPath = 'background1.png';
$string = $serialNumber;
$directory = "serial_image/".$string.".png";
$image = imagecreatefrompng($imgPath);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$font = 'arial.ttf';
$fontSize = 13;
$x = 20;
$y = 212;
imagettftext($image, $fontSize, 0, $x, $y, $color, $font, $string);

imagepng($image, $directory);
```

I call the function to create 10 images each with the unique serial number. They are created but then the browser stops and just shows this square.

I have tried `ob_start()` and `ob_flush()` with no luck

I think its a header issue.

Can someone please help with this one.